# Find data in any row in large paginated DataTable rendered server side

Tags: javascript, grails, datatables, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to find the row where column 1 equals a given value. My problem is that my table has about 500 rows, and is paginated. Somehow, it seems impossible to find data in other pages in a DataTable. I would have assumed that

```js
table.column(1).data().indexOf(givenPlanId);
```

would have been my answer, by apparently it can only find data that is already rendered by the DOM. I'm using grails, so the data is defined in groovy and the table is rendered server side. Is there any way I can search through all the data from JavaScript?

I also tried to iterate through all the pages like this:

```js
let row = -1;
while(row < 0) {
  row = table.column(1).data().indexOf(givenPlanId);
  if (row < 0) {
    table.page('next').draw('page');
  }
}
```

but this didn't work either, as it doesn't seem to change page to expose new data.

Comment: Can't do this client side because _all_ the data doesn't exist client side. You'll have to create a search endpoint that searches the table data server side and send back the result to the client.

Comment: @RandyCasburn but shouldn't it at least be possible to solve it by programmatically iterating through the pages?

Comment: Sure, I suppose, but then what's the use case for pagination at all then? Pull in all 500 rows and search them all at once. 500 is not a big number (depending on the number of columns).